# Should I use cat instead of dd here?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

The article [Encrypting a tar file using openssl](http://unixfoo.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/encrypting-tar-file-using-openssl.html) has the following line:

```
tar cvj ~/Projects/arc/ | openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -binary -outform DEM public.pem | dd of=arc.bckp
```

we can use cat instead of dd at the end... but should we? which one is better to be used here - cat or dd? and why?

I've 'time'-ed both options and can't see any significant advantage...

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why using dd here

Comment: that's how I found it here: [encrypting tar file using openssl](http://unixfoo.blogspot.com/2008/06/encrypting-tar-file-using-openssl.html)... I also wonder why :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither `cat` nor `dd` needs to be used; just say

```
tar cvj ~/Projects/arc/ | openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -binary -outform DEM public.pem > arc.bckp
```

Answer (score 2):

Only advantage you would get using dd is, "progress" can be displayed by sending SIGUSR1.

Else you can simply redirect. As said by jwpat7, no need to cat either.

One plus point of using dd instead of simple redirect is that you can easily `sudo dd` if required. That is not possible for redirection.

Comment: True. I will remember that. But as I intend to use it in a cron job it's better without 'progress' :)

Comment: progress is what pv is for

Comment: Yes, but pv will continuously keep putting progress information on stderr. If you want it to be only on-demand basis, then dd is an option.